# How to set 2 decimal places in sqlite select statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a sqlite table that has amount field with NUMERIC(10,5) value(I know data type meant not much in sqlite). I want to write a select statement that display amount in 2 decimal places.

```
    id      name             type        notnull      dflt_value      pk   
------- --------------- ---------- ----------- -------------- --- 
0        _id              integer       0                            1    
1        name             varchar       1                            0    
2        amount           NUMERIC(10,5) 0                            0    

SELECT _id, name, amount FROM accounts
```

Is it possible to convert the amount in two decimal places within the select statement, so I can display with two decimal places in the application.
I need to format in the select statement, don't wants to change the table structure. Thanks in advance.

Im using following code to populate the the list view in android

```
    cursor = dbAdapter.getAccountsTotals(); 
    startManagingCursor(cursor); 
    String[] from = new String[] { DbAdapter.KEY_ID, DbAdapter.KEY_NAME, DbAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT}; 
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.dis1, R.id.dis2, R.id.dis3}; 
    SimpleCursorAdapter trans = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.accts_row, cursor, from, to); 
setListAdapter(trans);
```

so can not format the results after fetching form the database. Please let me know it there is a way to assign formatted values in above code, thanks.

Comment: See this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846361/decimal-places-problem-with-sqlite)

Comment: [Here](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg04.htm) it is given to set the two decimal point valure while inserting the value in to table.

Comment: Please don't try to do presentation things (like formatting) in data layer. Try to separate concerns: get from the database your "data" (not a text string representing a number with some precision) and then, in your UI code (page / window / report / etc) present the formatted "string". As @Kennet says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT _id, name, ROUND(amount,2) FROM accounts
```

Following code will give you idea how you can do it

```
    

public class TestListView extends ListActivity {
  ...
  private DecimalFormat myCustDecFormatter = new DecimalFormat("########.00");
  ...
  ...
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }

private void fillData() {
    /* Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list */
    /* for mult accts, pass in acct name? */
    mEntryCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllEntries();
    startManagingCursor(mEntryCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{myDbAdapter.KEY_NMBR,myDbAdapter.KEY_DATE,myDbAdapter.KEY_DESCR,myDbAdapter.KEY_AMT};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txtnmbr, R.id.txtdate, R.id.txtdescr, R.id.txtamt};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.entryrow, mEntryCursor, from, to) {
        @Override
        public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
          super.setViewText(v, convText(v, text));
        }

    });

  }

  private String convText(TextView v, String text) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.txtamt:
        double dblAmt;
        //dblAmt = Double.valueOf(text);
        dblAmt = mEntryCursor.getDouble(AMT_COLUMN);
        return myCustDecFormatter.format(dblAmt);
    }
      return text;
    } 

}//end TestListView
```

Comment: +1 for the query; But it would be better to format the number in presentation layer, as I think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to have two decimal places. Not just rounded to 2 decimal places. for example 123.40  or 56.00 to show it as money value in a android application. by the way amount value is a type of NUMERIC(10,5) not float(my mistake)

Comment: Im using following code to populate the the list view in android cursor = dbAdapter.getAccountsTotals();
startManagingCursor(cursor);

String[] from = new String[] { DbAdapter.KEY_ID, DbAdapter.KEY_NAME, DbAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.dis1, R.id.dis2, R.id.dis3};

SimpleCursorAdapter trans = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
R.layout.accts_row, cursor, from, to);   
setListAdapter(trans);        so can not format the results. Please let me know it there is a way to assign formatted values to above code, thanks.

Comment: Thanks it's working now. dblAmt = mEntryCursor.getDouble(AMT_COLUMN); I had to make the AMT_COLUMN integer. then it's starts to work.

Answer (score 2):

Leave float value as it is in the database and format in presentation layer, somthing like this:

```
 float f = 1.23456f;
    NumberFormat instance = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    instance.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    System.out.println(instance.format(f));
```

Comment: I disagree.  A reasonable place for this kind of formatting is in a database view.  This approach is DRYer.